# Alignment problem with inline-block CSS attribute

Tags: html, alignment, css

[image: grid view]

I'm trying to create a grid menu on a web site. I am using `display: inline-block` to do so and it works very well, but for some reason, the last row doesn't line up.

I tried `display: inline-table` which works just as well but has the same problem. Each square with text is contained within a div that has the display attribute set to inline-block.

```
<div class="parcel">
    <a href="http://www.pizzahut.com">
    <img src="../img/computerGraphics.jpg"/>
    Computer Graphics </a>
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/web.jpg"/>
    Web
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/photography.jpg"/>
    Photography
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/models.jpg"/>
    3D Modeling
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/games.jpg"/>
    Games
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/graphicDesign.jpg"/>
    Visual Design
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/animation.jpg"/>
    Animation
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/illustration.jpg"/>
    Illustration
</div>
<div class="parcel">
    <img src="../img/other.jpg"/>
    Other
</div>
```

Does anyone know why the last row would do this?

Comment: Could you provide a URL to the page (if possible)? As it would be easier to see any problems that could be causing that.

Comment: I uploaded a temporary link here:

http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~jstrauss6/jrstrauss.net%20temp/original/myWork.html

Comment: or is there an alternate method to accomplishing the same task?

Comment: There might be a different way to do this. But, as Jason said below, the extra `<br>` might be causing that. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: yeah, that was my initial attempt to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-align: justify;` of your `contentText` div causes the small divs to have spaces in between, depending on the content of the divs. Try removing the `text-align: justify;` or change it to `text-align:center` from `contentText` and it will work fine.

I find this weird though, I tried using `justify` and the last line always not justify like in a newspaper.

Comment: +1 This is 100% correct... I just changed it to `text-align: center;` in Chrome Developer Tools and it worked. See this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/CWZ93DYVbgh

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without seeing the extra HTML and CSS but it could that you have link break or some white space or another element in there, before the last closing `div`, that is causing the last line to render differently.

**EDIT**

Had a look at the page you posted just now and @domanokz is right: change

```
div.contentText {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

to

```
div.contentText {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also removed that extra `br`, although it was not necessary for the fix.